# How to access data from multiple instances of the same child controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have two types of controllers:

- The first type of controller only appears once on an html page ("SingleChildController").
- The second type of controller appears twice on the same page ("MultipleChildController") and is differentiated by the value of its property "instance".

Both of these are nested within my ParentController (see code below).

**How can I access data from any of my 3 child controller instances in the ParentController?**

I have tried adding two services, one for the SingleChildController and one for the MultipleChildController, but it seems like by doing so I am duplicating a lot of code.  This is especially true in my actual code where each controller has many properties to monitor.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:** For further clarification, this view is for a form and I want to get all of my data back up into the ParentController so that I can submit my form.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ParentController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      var parent = this;

      parent.singleName = "";
      parent.multiple1Name = "";
      parent.multiple2Name = "";
    }
  ]);

  app.controller('SingleChildController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      var single = this;

      single.name = "";
    }
  ]);

  app.controller('MultipleChildController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      var multiple = this;

      multiple.instance = "";
      multiple.name = "";
    }
  ]);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ParentController as parent">
  <!-- I would like these to show the data that was inputted below -->
  ParentSingleName: {{parent.singleName}} <br />
  ParentMultiple1Name: {{parent.multiple1Name}} <br />
  ParentMultiple2Name: {{parent.multiple2Name}} <br /><br />

  <div ng-controller="SingleChildController as single">
    <input type="text" ng-model="single.name" />: {{single.name}}
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="MultipleChildController as multiple1" ng-init="multiple1.instance='first'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="multiple1.name" />: {{multiple1.instance}} - {{multiple1.name}}
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="MultipleChildController as multiple2" ng-init="multiple2.instance='second'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="multiple2.name" />: {{multiple2.instance}} - {{multiple2.name}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why u need to get child data?

Comment: You could create a factory using the observer pattern. With getter/setters for different values, a register method that registers per value and notifies the correct registered listeners when a certain value changes.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I need to get the child data because I need to submit the data as part of a form.

Comment: You should have all data in parent then. This is good. (You understand it if you end with directives for childs, you shall have smth like: <multiple data="childdata[0]"><multiple data="childdata[1]"> etc.)